# Pass in $(this) and addClass within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to pass in jQuery into a function so that I can later modify that element.

```
$(document).on('pjax:click', function(event) {
    Loader.send($(this));
});

$(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
    Loader.complete();
});
```

The Loader object

```
var Loader = {
    loading: false,
    lastPage: '',
    currentPage: '',
    target: null,

    send: function(_this)
    {
        this.lastPage = window.location.href;
        this.target = _this;
        this.load();
    },

    complete: function()
    {
        this.currentPage = window.location.href;

        // Handle the menu active states
        // Current (new page) url
        var cUrl = this.currentPage.replace('http://', '')
            .replace('https://', '')
            .replace('admin/', '')
            .split('/');

        // Previous page
        var pUrl = this.lastPage.replace('http://', '')
            .replace('https://', '')
            .replace('admin/', '')
            .split('/');

        // If new and old url's are different and they are different sections change the menu
        if(cUrl[1] !== pUrl[1] && this.lastPage !== this.currentPage)
        {
            $(".nav li").removeClass('active');

            this.target.addClass('active');

            console.log('Menu shit');
        }


        this.load();
    },

    load: function() {
        console.log(this);
        $("body").toggleClass('loading');
    }
};
```

I have tried both `this` and `$(this)` when I use `Loader.send()` however I cannot seem to add a class to it later in in the `complete` method.

Is there a way to send in through `Loader.send()` and later modify it?

Comment: You need `_this.addClass('active')`, not `this.target.addClass('active');`

Comment: `this.target` is holding the jQuery object. Using `_this` within `complete()` wouldn't do anything as it's not assigned. @4castle

Comment: @haim770 I have updated the code to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass whole document and add class at document level. Please provide full html so that we can try answering it.